# getlastknownlocation() return null and App is shutting down

Tags: android, gps, location

im trying to get current location on each several seconds and i do so with AlarmManager and LocationListener and Location Manager.
before setting the alarm i need to get current location for calculating the general distance.
when i run my app on AVD and set Lat & Long manually with DDMS the App works fine and do the job.
the problem is when the App is running on real device, the app is immediately shutting down (it fails also when i dont set position manually).
what can be the problem please? i only need to get current location when a button is clicked and each several seconds...

GPSTracker.Java :

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;


public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}


public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return location;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location =
                    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        Log.d("GPS is stopped", "GPS is stopped");
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}




@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

Alarm.Java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    /**  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
     wl.acquire();**/

    // Put here YOUR code.
    //Intent i= new Intent(this,AlarmActivity.class);
    //startActivity(i);

    try {


        gps = new GPSTracker(context);
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        Location CurrLoc = gps.getLocation();
        Location DistLoc = new Location("wow");
        DistLoc.setLatitude(32.159141);
        DistLoc.setLongitude(34.922564);
        float CurrDistance = CurrLoc.distanceTo(DistLoc);

        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("AlarmDistanceAndUserStatus", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        float AlarmDistance=prefs.getFloat("AlarmDistance",0);


        Log.d("distance invoke alarmRe",String.valueOf(AlarmDistance));
        Log.d("current distance is:",String.valueOf(CurrDistance));

       // Log.d("Run once -2",String.valueOf(AlarmActivity.RUN_ONCE));
       // Log.d("distance invoke alarm-2",String.valueOf(AlarmActivity.AlarmDistance));
        if(CurrDistance>=0 && CurrDistance<=50){
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("UserStatus",false);
            editor.commit();
            this.CancelAlarm(context);

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(newIntent);
        }
        else if(AlarmDistance>=CurrDistance){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(newIntent);
        }


        Toast.makeText(context, "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude + " distanceto:" + CurrDistance + " from AlaramSet!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("onReceive", "onReceive");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  //  Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

    //wl.release();
}


public void SetAlarm(Context context,int SecondsInterval) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, SecondsInterval);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), (1000 * SecondsInterval), pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Canceled!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

AlarmActivity.Java :

public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static boolean RUN_ONCE = true;

```
GPSTracker gps;
Alarm alarm;
SharedPreferences sharedpref;
boolean UserStatus=true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    alarm = new Alarm();
    Log.d("Run once -2", String.valueOf(RUN_ONCE));
    runOnce();
    sharedpref=getSharedPreferences("AlarmDistanceAndUserStatus", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpref.edit();
    UserStatus=sharedpref.getBoolean("UserStatus",true);
    Log.d("UserStatus now is:", String.valueOf(UserStatus));
    if(UserStatus){
        Button OkStopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.OkStopButton);
        OkStopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView WakeUpTimeTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.WakeUpTimeTextView);
        WakeUpTimeTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Button DidItButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DidItButton);
        Button MissItButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.MissItButton);
        DidItButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        MissItButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TextView DestArrivedTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.DestArrivedTextView);
        DestArrivedTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        Button OkStopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.OkStopButton);
        OkStopButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        TextView WakeUpTimeTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.WakeUpTimeTextView);
        WakeUpTimeTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Button DidItButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DidItButton);
        Button MissItButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.MissItButton);
        DidItButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MissItButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView DestArrivedTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.DestArrivedTextView);
        DestArrivedTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}

private void runOnce() {
    if (RUN_ONCE) {
        RUN_ONCE = false;
        gps = new GPSTracker(AlarmActivity.this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation) {

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            Location loc = gps.getLocation();
            Location dist = new Location("wow");
            dist.setLatitude(32.159058);
            dist.setLongitude(34.922536);
            float FirstDistance = loc.distanceTo(dist);
            Log.d("first distance",String.valueOf(FirstDistance));

            //System.currentTimeMillis()
            //interval time of distance check
            int SecondsInterval;
            if (FirstDistance >= 0 && FirstDistance <= 1000) SecondsInterval = 3;
            else if (FirstDistance > 1000 && FirstDistance <= 2000) SecondsInterval = 4;
            else if (FirstDistance > 2000 && FirstDistance <= 3500) SecondsInterval = 5;
            else SecondsInterval = 8;
            ///
            //check the distance to alarm user before dist. station
            int MissingCount = 2;//for example-import from db

            float AlarmDistance= (FirstDistance/ 10) * MissingCount;
            sharedpref=getSharedPreferences("AlarmDistanceAndUserStatus",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpref.edit();
            editor.putFloat("AlarmDistance",AlarmDistance);
            editor.putBoolean("UserStatus",true);
            editor.commit();


            alarm.SetAlarm(this,SecondsInterval);
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(newIntent);
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }


    }
}


public void StopOnClick(View v) {

    //  gps.stopUsingGPS();

    RUN_ONCE = true;
    sharedpref=getSharedPreferences("AlarmDistanceAndUserStatus",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putFloat("AlarmDistance",0);
    editor.putBoolean("UserStatus",true);
    editor.commit();
    alarm.CancelAlarm(this);
    //back to Home Page
}

public void DidItOnClick(View v){
    //Return to Home Page (e.g: MainActivity)
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(newIntent);


    RUN_ONCE = true;
    sharedpref=getSharedPreferences("AlarmDistanceAndUserStatus",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putFloat("AlarmDistance",0);
    editor.putBoolean("UserStatus", true);
    editor.commit();
}

public void MissItOnClick(View v){
    //go check altenative ways


    RUN_ONCE = true;
    sharedpref=getSharedPreferences("AlarmDistanceAndUserStatus",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putFloat("AlarmDistance",0);
    editor.putBoolean("UserStatus",true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

the failure:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.liorozit.gpstest/com.example.liorozit.gpstest.AlarmActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float android.location.Location.distanceTo(android.location.Location)' on a null object reference
```

there's an external class which move to AlarmActivity class by Intent and invoke it's OnCraete().
what can i do please to fix the prob and get my current location? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the Location in your activity and if is not needed to run it in a background, you could try this.

```
package com.jmarkstar.activitylocation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MyLocationListener locationListener;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        String bestEnabledProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestEnabledProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //YOU CODE
    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            }

            private void makeUseOfNewLocation(final Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    String message = "position: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + " accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                    longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

                    //YOUR CODE
                }
            }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks jmarkstar, so how for example in my AlarmActivity class should i use to get current location?

Comment: I have changed the answer, try it.